# Which table structure is more efficient performance wise

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

When creating a new post, I want the user to select one or more tags (up to 5) to be linked to this post.
I have posts, Tags and tagPosts tables.

Performance-wise, is it better to create 5 fields in the tagposts (TagId1 to TagId5) where each post_id will have a row in this table linked with the 5 tags (which ofcourse will be linked to the Tags table through 5 "tagposts.tagid = tags.id "). 
Or it would be better to just create a new row for each post_id Tag_id mapping?

Comment: It is better to have a separate row for each tag, under most circumstances.

Comment: What is the reason? I think fetching one row would be faster than fetching multiple rows, right ?

Comment: Certainly a single entry holding 5 tags is more efficient, so the technical answer to your question is that. But is that reason more important than other reasons? As @GordonLinoff correctly pointed out, _usually_ it is more intelligent to take a more generic approach. It is much more flexible in a variety of ways for later.

Comment: How would you query your first schema when you want to "select all posts having tags 'foo' and 'bar'"? I'd say this is a common requirement/feature.

Comment: You are right, it would be an "OR" hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot really measure the "efficiency" of a table.  You can measure the performance of queries.

Second, even from a space perspective, storing the values in one row may not be a win.  The storage is occupied by values, even when they are `NULL`.  In a proper junction/association table, there would be no rows.  So, if you had one or two tags per post on average, then the association table might use *less* space.

Third, managing the tags in separate columns is a pain.  To search for one tag value, you would have to do something like:

```
where @tag in (tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5)
```

Guess what?  That won't use any indexes.

And then if you want to ensure that all the tags are unique?  Can you use a unique constraint?  Uh, no.  Try a trigger with logic like:

```
(tag1 <> tag2 or tag1 is null or tag2 is null) and
(tag1 <> tag3 or tag1 is null or tag3 is null) and
. . .
-- there are lots of combinations so give yourself some time
```

Those are a few reasons why association tables are generally the best approach.  There may be some cases where using different columns is a good solution, but the default should be a proper junction/association table.